# Deploying and setup for windows applications project in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#

I want to create a setup  for a Windows Forms application using Visual Studio 2010 
that contains 5 projects

I do this :

- from **Solution Explorer** >right-click>**add** >and click **New Project**  and then
  expand **Setup and Deployment** and then select Visual Studio Installer.
- select **Setup** Project
- In the Name box, type testSetup.
- then right-click testSetup, click **Add** and then **Project Output**.

In the Add Project Output Group dialog box, what should I select?
Primary Output option for five time or what?

Comment: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12548/Visual-Studio-Windows-Application-Setup-Project) you can find some basic tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Simple right click on your setup project "Add -> Project Output then from the dropdown select the project you want, then repeat with the other projects as many as you need.

After that when you install it you will have all the *.exe for all the projects you have selected.(exe if you have selected PrimaryOutput)

PS: You was able to test it and find out a lot quicker then asking this question and waiting for reponse!

Comment: thank you soo mutch i do that befor i ask it but when i run setup